# Update single field in text file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I have this function:

```
def favourites():
name = input("Enter your name as you did when you signed up: ")
new_artist = input("Would you like to edit your favourite artist? y/n ").lower().strip()
if new_artist == 'yes' or new_artist == 'y':
    old_artist = input("Enter the favourite artist you used when signing up: ")
    artist = input("Enter your new favourite artist: ")
    usersFile = open('users.txt', 'r+')
    usersRec = usersFile.readline()
    # reads each line in the file
    while usersRec != "":
        # splits each record into fields 
        field = usersRec.split(',')
        if field[0] == name:
            usersFile.write(field[2].replace(old_artist, artist))
        usersRec = usersFile.readline()
    usersFile.close()
```

I have read a line in the text file and then split it into fields and i want to update a single field. Searched and found the update() function so tried that but it doesn't work and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should write to file in another stream, opening file for writing. Also made some corrections in readlines() method and 'replace' part (you should put the result into variable which is field[2]):

```
     import io
     import sys

def favourites():
    content=[]
    name = input("Enter your name as you did when you signed up: ")
    new_artist = input("Would you like to edit your favourite artist? y/n 
                  ").lower().strip()
    if new_artist == 'yes' or new_artist == 'y':
       old_artist = input("Enter the favourite artist you used when signing 
                     up: ")
       artist = input("Enter your new favourite artist: ")

         with open('users.txt', 'r+') as usersFile:
           usersRec = usersFile.readlines()
           print(usersRec)
# reads each line in the file
           for ur in usersRec:

    # splits each record into fields 
              field = ur.split(',')
              if field[0] == name:
                field[2] = field[2].replace(old_artist, artist)
                content.append(','.join(field))
              else: 
                content.append(','.join(field))
        usersRec = usersFile.readline()

     usersFile.close()

  writeToFile(content)


def writeToFile(content):
   with open('users.txt', 'w+') as usersFile:
      for line in content:
        usersFile.write(line)
   usersFile.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    favourites()
```